# Laravel Subdirectory Views

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

what I'm trying to do is set it up so that the user can go to "/project/index" ("/" being the route ofc) but I'm not quite sure how to do it in laravel?

What I currently have:

Routing:

`Route::get('project.index', array('as' => 'project/index', 'uses' => 'ProjectController@indexPage'));`

Also in routing:

`View::addLocation('project'); //Project View
 View::addNamespace('project', 'project');`

In my Project Controller:

```
public function indexPage()
    {
        return View::make('index', array('pageTitle' => 'Project Index'));
    }
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

**PS:** It's Laravel 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have your routing a little wrong. Try out the following

```
Route::get('project/index', ['as' => 'project.index', 'uses' => 'ProjectController@index']);
```

So the first parameter into the `Route::get()` function should be the URL the user is visiting for example `http://example.com/project/index`. The `as` key in the array provided is the name you're giving to the route.

By giving the route a name you can use this throughout your application, rather than using the url the user is visiting. For example you might want to generate a link to your route

```
<a href="{{ route('project.index') ">Link</a>
```

This will generate a link to `http://example.com/project/index`. This makes it convenient in the future should you wish to change your URLs without changing lots of links throughout your view files.

```
Route::get('foobar/index', ['as' => 'project.index', 'uses' => 'ProjectController@index']);
```

The URL generated through `route('project/index')` would now be `http://example.com/foobar/index`

Checkout the routing documentation for further information http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/routing

Comment: Brilliant! You helped me out a lot! +1 for you sir.